# WooCommerce Importing Products with Attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having trouble getting my product attributes to appear on the products pages in the backend. The products appear but with no attributes at all. What am I doing wrong? And should I be using global attributes or local? All products should have the same attributes but with different values.

I am working on a lighting shop the products have many attributes for example here's two of the attributes that I am trying to define;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to add the attributes here's a link to some documentation I found https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Import-Schema and also an image of how I did it to give you a better idea. I hope you find this useful.
[image]

Comment: this is CSV from import or to export?

Comment: This CSV is for importing products

Comment: so you want to say that you have succeeded in this way? I tried the same + using official Woo documentation (lik in your request topic) and unfortunately It can't work and I don't know why

Comment: Yeah this worked perfectly for me. So you're trying to import products to WooCommerce? if you can show me your spreadsheet I might be able to help

Comment: whole spreadsheet? I have to notice that I have products only with variations, not simple.